# Javascript em vários html's

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou aprendendo e utilizar o JavaScript e gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar scripts de um arquivo .js em vários outros .html, com funções e tudo mais. Se for possivel, é só chamar o arquivo .js no .html pela tag `<script>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você pode incluir o mesmo arquivo `javascript` em várias páginas usando a tag `script`.

Inclusive em páginas de outros sites. Veja o `jQuery` por exemplo, que pode incluir em qualquer página usando usando essa hospedagem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
```